# How to accept cookies in Windows Phone 7.5/8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cookies, windows-phone-8

How to accept cookies in windows phone 7.5/8?

In iPhone cookie accepts code like this

**NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
[cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];**

In android cookie accepts code like this

**CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);**

i search in forms but no one given solution about this. How to achieve this in windows phone. am building phonegap windows phone package this issue rises while login authentication, in IOS and Android i solved by accepting cookies with above code but how to do in Windows Phone

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a HttpWebRequest you only need to add a CookieContainer.

```
var container = new CookieContainer();    
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
request.CookieContainer = container;
```

This will store all the cookies automatically. If you want to use the cookies in all the following request you need to use the same CookieContainer in all request and not instantiate a new one every time.